# About android JSON parser

Tags: android, json

I have a long string from android Http get like this:

```
{"movies":[
{"movieId":"fmen71229238","eTitle":"Mission: Impossible - Ghost Protocol","cTitle":"不可能的任務：鬼影行動","imageUrl":"http://test.mobibon.com.tw/MovieGoTest/Pics/pl_fmen7122923814_s.jpg","releaseDate":"2011/12/15","saleType":"0"},
{"movieId":"fstw79905171","eTitle":"Seediq Bale","cTitle":"賽德克．巴萊(上)太陽旗","imageUrl":"http://test.mobibon.com.tw/MovieGoTest/Pics/pl_fstw7990517114_s.jpg","releaseDate":"2011/9/9","saleType":"0"},
{"movieId":"fytw91390391","eTitle":"You Are the Apple of My Eye","cTitle":"那些年，我們一起追的女孩","imageUrl":"http://test.mobibon.com.tw/MovieGoTest/Pics/pl_fytw9139039102_s.jpg","releaseDate":"2011/8/19","saleType":"0"}
]}
```

the string is JSON format, and I want it be sort in different array,and display in a Listview, so I used the JSON paser like this

```
JSONArray result = new JSONArray(retSrc);
        for(int i = 0;i < result.length(); i++)
        {
        JSONObject stock_data = result.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.i("bird","eTitle:"+stock_data.getString("eTitle"));
        }
        } finally {
        }
        }
```

p.s retSrc is the long string from site

But the Log

```
Log.i("bird","eTitle:"+stock_data.getString("eTitle"));
```

logs nothing.

I expect it log like this:

> Mission: Impossible - Ghost Protocol  Seediq Bale.....etc

Comment: 你能不能把問題寫清楚點，什麼叫不工作，是沒有得到 title 還是沒有排序？

Comment: What is the issue you are having? What is the log you are getting?

Comment: 以修改，感謝提醒
fix already,thanks for tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also make use of Gson, which provides you api's for Json parsing. its very easy just you need to create type of object you want.

Answer (score 3):

here is the code to parse it

```
String jsonData = "{\"movies\":["
                + "{\"movieId\":\"fmen71229238\",\"eTitle\":\"Mission: Impossible - Ghost Protocol\",\"cTitle\":\"??????:????\",\"imageUrl\":\"http://test.mobibon.com.tw/MovieGoTest/Pics/pl_fmen7122923814_s.jpg\",\"releaseDate\":\"2011/12/15\",\"saleType\":\"0\"},"
                + "{\"movieId\":\"fstw79905171\",\"eTitle\":\"Seediq Bale\",\"cTitle\":\"???.??(?)???\",\"imageUrl\":\"http://test.mobibon.com.tw/MovieGoTest/Pics/pl_fstw7990517114_s.jpg\",\"releaseDate\":\"2011/9/9\",\"saleType\":\"0\"},"
                + "{\"movieId\":\"fytw91390391\",\"eTitle\":\"You Are the Apple of My Eye\",\"cTitle\":\"???,????????\",\"imageUrl\":\"http://test.mobibon.com.tw/MovieGoTest/Pics/pl_fytw9139039102_s.jpg\",\"releaseDate\":\"2011/8/19\",\"saleType\":\"0\"}"
                + "]}";
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONArray movieArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("movies");
        JSONObject movieObj = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < movieArray.length(); i++) {
            movieObj = movieArray.optJSONObject(i);
            if (null != movieObj) {
                String mId = movieObj.optString("movieId");
                String title = movieObj.optString("eTitle");
                String cTitle = movieObj.optString("cTitle");
                String imageUrl = movieObj.optString("imageUrl");
                String releaseDate = movieObj.optString("releaseDate");
                String saleType = movieObj.optString("saleType");
                System.out.println("movieID [" + mId + "] eTitle [" + title
                        + "] cTitle [" + cTitle + "] imgUrl [" + imageUrl
                        + "] relDate [" + releaseDate + "] saleType ["
                        + saleType + "]");
            }
```

Comment: thanks, bur the string 「jsonData」 is different to the string i provide, it already inserts many 「/」 in it.....
and the string must load from site...so i don't want it wright in my code....but still thanks for your help!

Comment: yes..i have to escape the "" that's why i did that and its not effecting your string anyways its the same..and just make a function and pass that server retured string as an argument to this function and use that..hope it helps and did you accepted the answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the top level of the json file is not a `JSONArray` but a `JSONObject`.

Use something like following:

```
   JSONObject obj = new JSONOBject(retSrc);
   JSONArray movieArray = obj.getJSONArray("movies");
   //then process the movie as you did
```